# Express the length a, b, c, and d in the figure in terms of the trigonometric ratios of θ.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

#### Problem

Express the length a, b, c, and d in the figure in terms of the trigonometric ratios of $θ$. (See the image below)

[image: updated]

#### Progress

I can figure out $c$ usng the pythagorean theorem. $a^2+b^2=c^2$ which would be $2$. Is that correct? How do I solve the rest?

---

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7ZoF.jpg)

Comment: What have you done so far and where are you stuck? If you tell us how far you've gotten we can give you better help.

Comment: Perhaps the [trigonometric functions Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) could be enlightening.

Comment: I can figure out c usng the pythagorean theorem. a^2+b^2=c^2 which would be 2. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have marked 5 points P,Q,R,S,T in your diagram.

Consider the triangle formed by points P, S and T.
Do you agree that

- Length of PS = c
- Length of ST = b
- Length of PT = 1

It is a right-angle triangle, so apply Pythagoras theorem,

> square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the
>   other two sides

We get $b^2+1^2=c^2$

We know that $\sin \theta=\Large \frac{\text{opposite side}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$and $\cos\theta = \Large \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$(Now, refer triangle PST and write down write $\sin\theta,\cos\theta$)

Now, simplify, substitue to express b and c only in terms of trig ratio, that is b=some tri ratio($\theta$) and c=some trig ratio($\theta$)

Similarly, for triangle PRQ
Do you agree that

- Length of PQ = d
- Length of RQ = a
- Length of PR = 1

Answer (score 0):

Compute $\sin(\theta)$, $\cos(\theta)$ and $\tan(\theta)$ using your picture. What do you see?

Comment: I see that sides d and b are 1 length in size. Am I correct?

Comment: If that is correct I can figure out c usng the pythagorean theorem. a^2+b^2=c^2 which would be 2. Is that correct?